# Is there any reason I shouldn't store my keystore in version control?

Tags: java, android, security, keystore, android-keystore

I'm using a keystore (.jks) to store the certificate I use to sign my Android applications. The Android documentation and community have impressed on me the importance of **never** losing this file, but I haven't found any guidance on where I should keep it.

Would storing it in Git be a terrible idea (i.e. would it have security consequences)?

Assume that the keystore itself and the private keys inside both have strong passwords on them.

Comment: As a specific question relevant only to software developers, and one with potentially severe consequences, this seems entirely on-topic.

Comment: I am (obviously) not totally familiar with keystores or what you use them for, but my only encounters with them are programming (using them is not optional if you want to make an Android app). Unless they have other use cases I would say they fall under "tools used primarily for programming".

Answer (score 19):

Anyone with read access to your Git repo will get the private key.  This is considered a security issue and for that reason it is not recommended.  If your GIT repo is completely private meaning no one but you has access to it (NOT A private repo on i.e. GitHub, but rather git repo on local disk or in the infrastructure you control in 100%) then putting your private key there is as safe as safe your local infrastructure is.

> Assume that the keystore itself and the private keys inside both have strong passwords on them

Note that password is your last way of defense in case of your ("public") private key. If it will be compromised in any way (guessed, stolen, cracked) then it's over.

Additionally, I am more than certain that not all (if any) of devs needs access to **release keys**. If you need them to have it, hand it using other channels than repo (i.e. GPG encrypted mail etc). But I'd first rethink your security policy.

Comment: Stupidly I didn't specify that I would still put a password on the private key, I've edited the question to reflect that now :)

Comment: @ZoFreX - why depend on the password to secure the key?  It's probably much more easily guessed than the key itself.  And **anyone with access to your repo and a binary signed by you can have infinite tries at guessing it**, on as fast a collection of AWS instances as they care to purchase.  Even if your repo is private today, at some point you might share it or store it offsite, and forget about this risk.

Comment: Anyone with access to a binary signed by me alone can have infinite tries at guessing the key itself, on as fast a collection of AWS instances as they care to purchase.

Comment: Wish you luck in recreating pkey from signed up in sane. finite time.

Comment: That was kind of my point... the password can be arbitrarily large, so good luck brute forcing it!

Comment: Changes can be weak. Can be guesses (far too often). Can be revealed with force. Far harder to do any of these with pkey

Comment: The key stored in the .jks file is usually 2048 bits. Password is probably much weaker and can be easily brute force. You are absolutely right that the password can be 2048 bits long as well, but I pretty sure you cannot remember such a long password and you'll need to store it in a file, somewhere -> back to square one...

Answer (score 10):

To update your App you need two things:

- Access to the Google Play Developer console that owns the application.
- An APK signed with the correct keystore

By putting the certificate into your repository and sharing it with your developers you are giving up one security token.

If your Google Play Dev Console account is secure then you should be fine. But it depends on your szenario.

Putting it into the repository is much easier:

- Your repository is cloned on many places and usually backed up properly.
- Your developer team can use gradle to sign your production release automatically.

Many people prefer putting it on one or many SD Cards and put it somewhere. But most people don't have a place called "somewhere" in their office. Can it still be read in a few years?

Two more consideration:

1. If the product owner of the android app changes in your company you never know if the old owner still has a copy and nobody knows who has access to it already. You can't change the key. So if the key is once passed from one person to another, it must be assumed insecure.
2. Of course, you can keep it completely private. It is secured by your password which nobody knows. But what happens if you die? Someone might want to update your app. It is not possible. A private key which is kept private is lost when you die.

So I think putting it in your repository is fine. Take care to secure your Google account. For this account the password can be changed, two-faktor can be activated and so on.